# how to further refine expss table format?

Tags: r, expss

I am trying to improve my table design using `expss`. My current design is shown below using the following code:

```
library(expss)
# bogus example data
x<-structure(list(visits= structure(c(17, 2, 23, 1, 21), label = "Total # Home Visits", class = c("labelled", "numeric")), months_enrolled = structure(c(21.42474, 51.105, 52.474, 53.75, 60.0392105), label = "Enrollment Duration (months)", class =c("labelled","numeric")), marital2 = structure(c("Married", NA, "Married", "Married", "Married"), label = "Marital Status", class = c("labelled", "character")), Relationship2 = structure(c("Mother", "Mother", "Mother", "Mother", "Mother"), label = "Relationship (recoded)", class = c("labelled", "character"))), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

htmlTable(x %>% 
tab_cells(visits,months_enrolled) %>%
tab_rows(marital2, Relationship2,  total()) %>%     tab_stat_fun(Mean = w_mean, "Valid N" = w_n, method = list) %>%
tab_pivot() %>%
set_caption("Table 6: Bogus Visits and Duration by Characteristics") %>% 
htmlTable(.,css.cell = c("width: 220px", # first column width
                          rep("width: 50px", ncol(.) - 1))))
```

I'd like to improve the table design by placing the mean statistics for Home Visits and Enrollment Duration as columns, thus saving a row for each level of Marital Status (and other vars in `tab_rows`). How is this achieved?  Also, is it possible to shade alternate rows?

[image: expssTable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, the simplest way is to transpose table:

```
htmlTable(x %>% 
              tab_cells(visits, months_enrolled) %>%
              tab_cols(marital2, Relationship2,  total()) %>%  
              tab_rows(total(label = "|")) %>% 
              tab_stat_fun(Mean = w_mean, "Valid N" = w_n) %>%
              tab_pivot() %>%
              tab_transpose() %>% 
              set_caption("Table 6: Bogus Visits and Duration by Characteristics") %>% 
              htmlTable(.,css.cell = c("width: 220px", # first column width
                                       rep("width: 50px", ncol(.) - 1))))
```

[image]